# What is the quickest way to extract 100 K images from an Oracle DB?

Tags: c#, oracle10g, blob, rdbms, relational-database

The options I am thinking of are:

1) C# Console Based App to extract images to the windows file system.

2) java app to extract images on the unix based file system.

Any other method that you can think of, please let me know. There are approximately 101,234 records and each BLOB column may have a file between 1 MB to 6 MB.

Comment: I don't think the Java/C# choice will have any significant impact on the time. Use whatever you are the most comfortable with. The time required to run is more likely to be constrained by disk or network bandwith.

Comment: If this is a one-off : Probably the "quickest" here is to do the absolute simplest thing possible and click "go" sooner... Anything more elegant/sophisticated will take more dev effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want speed, I would recomend you to use a PL/SQL stored procedure to save the images to files directly. It should be quicker than an external program

```
DECLARE
t_blob BLOB;
t_len NUMBER;
t_file_name VARCHAR2(100);
t_output UTL_FILE.file_type;
t_TotalSize number;
t_position number := 1;
t_chucklen NUMBER := 4096;
t_chuck raw(4096);
t_remain number;
BEGIN
-- Get length of blob
SELECT DBMS_LOB.getlength (PHOTO), ename || '_1.jpg'
INTO t_TotalSize, t_file_name FROM DEMO WHERE ENAME ='moon';
t_remain := t_TotalSize;
-- The directory TEMPDIR should exist before executing 
t_output := UTL_FILE.fopen ('TEMPDIR', t_file_name, 'wb', 32760);
-- Get BLOB 
SELECT PHOTO INTO t_blob FROM DEMO WHERE ENAME ='moon';
-- Retrieving BLOB
WHILE t_position < t_TotalSize 
LOOP
DBMS_LOB.READ (t_blob, t_chucklen, t_position, t_chuck);
UTL_FILE.put_raw (t_output, t_chuck);
UTL_FILE.fflush (t_output);
t_position := t_position + t_chucklen;
t_remain := t_remain - t_chucklen;
IF t_remain < 4096
THEN
t_chucklen := t_remain;
END IF;
END LOOP;
END;
```

Check this [Link](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_extract_jpg_image_photo_sql_file.htm)

Comment: I did choose this as an answer. I have been reading up on asktom.oracle.com as well. The issue with this approach is that I need to get access to a folder on the *nix environment, where my DBA is loath to grant that to me.

Once again, thanks for your contribution.